# c function with void parameter

Tags: c, pointers

The function `func` takes void parameter `buf`. I want to insert values from 1 to 10 into `buf` by calling `func`. However, the addresses of `buf` are different in `func` and `main` and the printed values are not from 1 to 10. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks!

```
void func(int n, void *buf);

int main()
{
    void *buf;
    func(10,buf);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d\n", ((char*)buf)[i]);
    }
    printf("in main, after func: %p\n",buf);
}

void func(int n, void *buf)
{
    (char*)buf;
    char my_array[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        my_array[i]=i;
    }

    buf = my_array;
    printf("in func: %p\n",buf);
}
```

Comment: "The function func takes void parameter buf" - no, it does not! `buf` is a `void *`, not a `void` (whatever that would be). And your `main` signature should be `int main(void)`. And why do you keep your compiler from helping you? Never use `void *` if it is not really necessary. The same for casts. Write type-safe code, anything else is a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `buf` to a pointer that points to memory on the stack (i.e. `my_array`). Since it is no longer valid as soon as the program leaves `func` this does not work.

Either use dynamic memory, but then you need to free it explicitly. Another option is to create the memory outside and only fill it inside of `func`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char* buf, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        buf[i]=i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char buf[10];
    func(buf, sizeof(buf));

    for(int i=0; i < sizeof(buf); i++) {
        printf("%d\n", buf[i]);
    }
}
```

Apart from that: Never use `void*` unless you have a VERY good reason for it!

Comment: so how can i insert values into buf with func(int n, void *buf)?

Comment: Actually he doesn't return it.

Comment: @immibis What is (or is not) returned?

Comment: @immibis ok you got me :-) I will rewrite it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate your memory outside of your function, otherwise it will not be valid when you return, because it was allocated on the stack.

```
void func(int n, int *buf);

int main()
{
    const int n = 10;
    int my_array[n];

    func(n, my_array);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d\n", ((int*)my_array)[i]);
    }
    printf("in main, after func: %p\n", my_array);
}

void func(int n, int *buf)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        buf[i] = i;
    }
}
```